# plupload how to disable / enable Add files button?

Tags: javascript, plupload

I've been trying pluploader out to front end upload files to my Photo gallery webpage and it works well. Basically just followed the examples on the website. But I would like to disable the Add files button initially until user has selected an upload destination "album" which they do by pressing a button click handler I implemented (see album-select onclick below). I have managed to disable the Add button in the constructor as shown, but I'm having no luck re-enabling it when user presses the album button. Any ideas how to implement re-enabling the Add files button from my own button press? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var uploader = $("#upl").plupload({
      // General settings
      url : g_homeUrl + "get-from-browser/",
    
      // Maximum file size
      max_file_size : '10mb',
    
      // Specify what files to browse for
      filters : [
          {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"}
      ],
    
      // Sort files

      sortable: true,
    
      // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
      dragdrop: true,

       // To disable Add files button. 
       buttons: {
        browse: false
      },
    
      // Views to activate
      views: {
          list: true,
          thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
          active: 'thumbs'
      }
    
    });
    
    uploader.init();

    uploader.bind('complete', function(up, fl){
      console.log('Completed uploading ' + fl.files.length + " files"); 
    });

    uploader.bind('error', function(up, err) {
      document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
    });

    document.getElementById('album-select').onclick = function(e) {
      albSet = e.target.dataset.album;
      var albTitle = e.target.dataset.title;
      var html = "Upload to album " + albTitle + "<br/>";
      html += "Click add files to select your images for upload";
      document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = html;
      // How to enable browse (Add files) button if disabled in constructor?
      //uploader.disableBrowse(false) says not a function??
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: Use the `setOption` method to overwrite that particular option ...? https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Uploader#methods

Comment: Thanks. I tried setOption but it give the same error "not a function" as disableBrowse does, so I think I don't understand the context of these methods. Presumably I can't call them here?

Comment: What API version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.3.9 that's what the zip file name is.

Comment: Documentation of this thing doesn't appear to be all too good :-/ Maybe you need to use a syntax similar to what's used here, https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/jquery/jquery_ui_widget.html#L97 ...? `$("#upl").plupload('methodname', { /* parameters */ })`

Comment: No luck, same error. I found a work around - just used jQuery to hide and show on the button ID.   $("#upl_browse").show()  and .hide()